# How to change background of a cell when the name contains the search bar text?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, searchbar

I am trying to change the color of a cell if the name of the cell matches with part of the text in the search bar. Almost as the cell is being highlighted. I am using a search bar and a table view for this.

I have tried this code with the help of the comments but I still can't figure it out:

```
let allElements = ["Hydrogen", "Helium", ...]

var searchElement = [String]()
var searching = false
var myIndex = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("row selected : \(indexPath.row)")

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let hydrogenSearchSegue = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "hydrogenView") as! hydrogenViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(hydrogenSearchSegue, animated:true)




     }

}

}


extension searchViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searching == true {

        return searchElement.count

    } else {

        return allElements.count

    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if searching == true {

        cell?.textLabel?.text = searchElement[indexPath.row]

    } else {

        cell?.textLabel?.text = allElements[indexPath.row]

    }

    return cell!

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let string = allElements[indexPath.row]

    if searchElement.contains(string) {

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    } else {

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    }

}

}

extension searchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        searchElement = allElements.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

The goal was to try and use the .filter to separate the cells that don't contain the search bar text with what does. Then change the color of the cell if it does contain that text.

Comment: Here is the flow you should follow, on every text change, you update the datasource, and refresh the table. And the model that is backing up your cell, should have a `isHighlighted` flag or something, which is default set to false, and switches to true, when you filter it in your text did change method.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you mean when you say "the model that is backing up your cell." Is that one of the functions? Where would I add this `isHighlighted` flag? Would I create a variable for it and then create an if statement declaring when it's true to run the cell background color code?

Comment: 1. when are you setting `searching = false`? 2. in your `cellForRow` and `numberOfRows` you are setting the dataSource based on your `searching` field, but in the `willDisplayCell` you are searching considering that the cell is filled from the `allElements` array. I dont think you need a `searching` flag, instead just empty the `searchElement` array in `searchBarCancel..`. Just go through your code breakpoint by breakpoint and you'll know where you are wrong

Answer (score 4):

This is something that you can do.

you can filter your search array whenever there is a change in search text.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

//here searchElement is your searched array. and allElements is your main array
         searchElement = allElements.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) 
// or your filter logic whatever it is. 

//and then you refresh your tableview here
myTableView.reloadData()
 }
```

and in `willDisplayCell` you do this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let string = allElements[indexPath.row]
//if your search array contains the current cell, then you can show the cell as highlighted.
    if searchElement.contains(string) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
//But make sure to empty your search array in case you are not searching.

}
```

And to reset it, you can set your searchElements array to empty.

//NOTE: The `willDisplay` Method need not go inside the `textDidChange` method

Comment: I updated the post with the full code I'm using to try and make it more specific. I am still unable to get it to work and I can't figure out what's wrong because from what you gave me, it looks like it should work.